# Implementing multi-theme support in a Backbone.js application

Tags: javascript, html, templates, design-patterns, backbone.js

I have a Backbone.js SmartTV application that serves VOD and live TV content. This is currently laid out as you might expect- top nav, sub nav, and a main content area below to display assets for a given category.

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|  Top Nav                                           |
|                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|  Sub Nav                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|  Content                                           |
|  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  |
|  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |
|  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |
|  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |
|  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |
|  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  |
|  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  |
|  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |
|  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |
|  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |
|  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |      |  |
|  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  +------+  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Content is served by a Rails app hosted separately (which makes up the administrative side).  The application makes one big JSON request to the Rails API on startup, parses everything into Backbone models, then renders this on the page.  Then the client app periodically queries the server to check for updates.

At some point I need to implement theming from the administrative side so that customers can brand their TV experience.  The most basic way I can think to approach this is to allow administrators to select from a series of options (logo, colors, sizes, etc).  This seems easy enough to do, as these options could simply be passed to the client in the initial JSON payload.  The problem though would be that they would still be glued to the same basic layout.

What I really need to figure out is how to allow users to drastically alter the layout.  For instance, moving navigation to the left side of the screen, or the bottom, or having no high-level navigation at all (just a cluster of assets on the screen).

I'm not sure how to even approach that in a Backbone application since that goes far beyond just changing CSS.  It would require completely different remote navigation logic, completely different Backbone views, and so on.

I'm wondering if anyone has ever encountered a requirement similar to this with Backbone, or how you would approach structuring something like this.

My gut is telling me that I could restructure my app as follows:

- templates/

  - default/

    - js/
    - config.js
    - router.js
    - views/
    - html/
    - css/
  - side_nav/

    - js/
    - config.js
    - router.js
    - views/
    - html/
    - css/
- core/

  - models/
  - modules/
  - application.js

However, this seems close to writing a whole new app for each separate theme, with the only shared code being in the various models/modules.  Is there a more elegant way to approach this?

Comment: This really should be a case of simply changing the css. If it isn't then something is wrong. You can give your users a set of predefined css templates, or let them enter their own if they want. This would also let them put in their own branding.

Comment: Visually, yes I could simply allow changing CSS. But since this is a TV app, there is logic around remote control navigation that would need to change depending on different layouts.